# The 'ClientId' option must be provided with AzureAdB2C middleware

Tags: .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular app that is able to authenticate with azure b2c but also a custom web api but when adding in the middleware for the .net core web api I'm getting an error which says a configuration item is missing. I have everything in azure configure with expose api, scope, give permissions, etc but I am getting this error:

> Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HM729054ALE1", Request id "0HM729054ALE1:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.

It's like the appsettings is not binding. Why?

---

I'm only using local accounts for now so I don't have any other Identity providers setup so should work with the clientid from the web api. I'm not sure what I'm missing

```
//tried this 
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

//this as well
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));


{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://{domain}.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111", 
    "Domain": "{domain}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_SignupSign"    
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

startup

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;


namespace WepApi1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            //    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

            services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddControllers();
                       
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true);
            }));

          

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
          
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could share more details about Startup.cs? This [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C) works well.

Comment: Well that sample is just a MVC app for logging in which I have an angular app working with the login, it's the web api that is protected by AzureB2C that I'm trying to get to work. I don't even have Authorize on the controller. It's throwing errors on this line: services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

I actually need this example to work: 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C

Answer (score 1):

Well the entire issue turned out to be Kestrel. As soon as I used IIS Express everything worked. Unreal

Answer (score 0):

My dependency injection look like this:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
```

And this this my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "[YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE]"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[YOUR APP DOMAIN HERE]",
    "TenantId": "[YOUR APP'S HERE]",
    "ClientId": "[YOUR APP'S HERE]",
    "Scopes": {
      "Read": [ "[YOUR APP'S].Read" ],
      "Write": [ "[YOUR APP'S].ReadWrite" ]
    },
    "AppPermissions": {
      "Read": [ "[YOUR APP'S].Read.All" ],
      "Write": [ "[YOUR APP'S].ReadWrite.All" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Forget to add AzureAd setting to `appsettings.json` file also causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

##### Alternate Way Of Resolving The Issue

1. Depending on which config file it resides in, should be top level of `appsettings.json`, it may not be loaded.

   - So try a different config file
   - try putting it in the `User Secrets` (*In Visual Studio right click the project and select `Manage User Secrets` config*.)
2. To test if you are getting a client id, debug into the configuration by asking for the client id such as

   `builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");`

If #2 fails the the configuration engine is not finding the `AzureAd` section or there is no `ClientId`.

Once #2 succeeds make sure the **configuration section** `AzureAd` is being passed into the identity provider such as

`.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))`